# Dúvida sobre herança hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

Eu tenho 3 classes / 2 tabelas: funcionario / secretaria :

Funcionario

vendedor extends funcionario

secretaria extends funcionario

eu queria fazer uma herança single table com vendedor e funcionario

e uma herança joined com secretaria e funcionario
é possível fazer isso?

```
classe funcionario;

@Entity(name="Funcionario")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "tipo", length = 1, discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING)
@DiscriminatorValue("F")
@Table(name = "funconarios")
public abstract class Funcionario implements Autenticar {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "codFuncionario")
    private String codFuncionario;
```

vendedor:

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue(value = "V")
public class Vendedor extends Funcionario implements BonusSalario{
}
```

e como eu faria na classe secretaria?

```
public class Secretaria extends Funcionario implements BonusSalario{
}
```

Comment: Cara, acredito que seja melhor vc pensar em composição, px: Vendedor tem dados de funcionario (ai vc pode anotar com @Embeded) class Vendedor { private Funcionario funcionario}

Comment: @cezar mas tipo a classe vendedor eu nem precisaria extender pois vai ter os mesmo atributos que funcionario e a mesma tabela, vc poderia responder com um exemplo usando esse @ embeded para que eu possa entender melhor como utilizar isso na classe gerente?

Comment: Acho que usando apenas JOINED deve resolver, só que no caso seriam criadas 3 tabelas, onde a chave primária de funcionário seria a chave extrangeira dos filhos, os atributos comuns a vendedor e secretaria ficariam na classe abstrata

Comment: https://memorynotfound.com/hibernate-jpa-joined-table-inheritance-example/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se entendi corretamente, este mapeamento **NÃO** teria o sentido correto, pois:

No Single table com vendedor e funcionário iria gerar uma única tabela:

- Tabela funcionário: contendo todas informações juntas vendedor/funcionário

E o joined com secretaria e funcionário teriam 2 tabelas:

- Tabela funcionário: só com as informações do funcionário;
- Tabela secretária: com as informações de secretária e uma FOREIGN
  KEY para    a tabela de funcionário

Se for possível fazer esta mistura desta forma a secretária teria no mapeamento na tabela informações internas do vendedor, exemplo de como ficaria o mapeamento de forma resumida e visual:

[image: Exemplo do mapeamento]

Do meu ponto de vista o mais correto seria usar o **JOINED** em ambos mapeamentos

[image: Joined]

**Referencia JOINED table:** [hibernate docs](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#entity-inheritance-joined-table)

Comment: nesse caso eu teria 3 tabelas no banco / vendedor/ secretaria / funcionario não é?

Comment: Sim, na verdade no seu caso acho que se encaixaria corretamente o @MappedSuperclass [hibernate docs](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#entity-inheritance-mapped-superclass) vou editar a resposta depois